# C++ runtime error in my class

Tags: c++, list, runtime-error

I have tried to make my own list for C++.
I have this Class:

```
template <class T>
class List
{
private:
T *value, *valueHelper;
int valueSize;

 public:
int size;

List()
{
    valueSize = 2;
    value = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T) * valueSize);
    size = 0;
}


void Add(T val)
{
    size++;

    if (size > valueSize)
    {
        valueSize *= 2;
        valueHelper = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T) * valueSize);

        memcpy(valueHelper, value, sizeof(T) * (valueSize / 2));
        free(value);
        value = valueHelper;;
    }

    value[size - 1] = val;

}

T operator[](int P)
{
    return value[P];
}

};
```

When I try to use it in the main it works fine to Int.
Buy to Struct it is doing problems:

```
struct Material
{
string materialName;
int faceNum;
int meshNum;

Material(): materialName(""), faceNum(0), meshNum(0){};
};


void main() 
{
    List <Material> myList = List<Material>();
    myList.Add(Material());
}
```

I got runtime error in the class on the line:

```
value[size - 1] = val;
```

Why?

Comment: Start with removing `malloc()`/`free()` from this entire thing and using `operator new`/`operator delete[]`.

Comment: Why new and delete are better?

Comment: @user2320928 because this is c++

Comment: @billz This is not the answer.

Comment: No, not because this is C++. Mainly because "new" calls the constructor. However in this case an array is being created so I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: @lulyon I didn't post answer, it's just a comment. ;)

Comment: Actually now with new it is working. But I cant understand why

Comment: What if with `value = static_cast<T*> malloc(sizeof(T) * valueSize);`? I can't trust `(T *)` type conversion, but I know `sizeof` macro is ok with template.

Comment: There is a constructor ! :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because i did not pay attention to a third error in your original code ! The operator[] need to return by reference, not by value.

```
T & operator[](int P) {
    assert( P < m_size );
    return m_elems[P];
}
```

You probably want the const version too

```
T const & operator[](int P) const {
    assert( P < m_size );
    return m_elems[P];
}
```

Comment: Umm still the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two errors in your code :

```
- you cannot use memcpy to move class memory from one place to another except in very few cases. a std::string is not one of these cases.
- When you call an operator= it needs that the receiver is well formed, and it means that it is construct.
```

You hit the second error, because the value[0] is never construct, when you call the operator=, it is filled with garbage, and most probably try to delete random pointer value.

I imagine you prefer to construct object only when it is need, just like std::vector ? So a better implementation would be :

```
template <class T>
class List {
    int m_size;
    int m_capacity;
    T * m_elems;

    public:
    List() : 
        m_size(),
        m_capacity( 2 ),
        m_elems( (T*) malloc( sizeof(T) * m_capacity ) ) {
    }

    void Add( T const & val ) {
        if ( m_size + 1 > m_capacity ) {
            m_capacity *= 2;
            T * elems = (T*) malloc( sizeof(T) * m_capacity );

            for( int i = 0 ; i != m_size ) {
                new ( elems + i ) T( m_elems[i] ); // copy constructor
                ( m_elems + i )->~T(); // manually call the destructor
            }
            free( m_elems ); 
            m_elems = elems;
        }
        new( m_elems + m_size++ ) T( val );
    }

    T operator[](int P) {
        assert( P < m_size );
        return m_elems[P];
    }
};
```